# Navbar button appears much too wide, when Navbar is collapsed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a Navbar with Bootstrap 4. The "Logout" button on the left side in the Navbar appears much to wide, when the navbar is collapsed.
How can I fix the big "Logout" button if the navbar is collapsed??

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <strong>Navbar</strong>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-dark" href="x">Logout<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: i can't see the logout button when i collapse the navbar...

Comment: Just run the code snippet...

Comment: i already ran the code and wrote that comment. when the navbar is "**collapsed**", logout button is not visible [screenshot](https://imgur.com/t7FVZTk).

Comment: ok i took it the wrong way. by "collapsed" you mean the buttons on the navbar is hidden in the hamburger, right?

Comment: - when the screen width is small enough. and not about whether the menu is opened or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the logout button in a `form.form-inline` like in the [official docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#forms), and the button is no longer stretched.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <strong>Navbar</strong>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <form class="form-inline">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="x">Logout<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```